# How to split key values in a string

Tags: python

I have a string in the following format.

```
"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key1":"value3,value4"
```

How can I split the string so that it can be saved in a dictionary like this,

```
{
  key1 : [value1, value3, value4]
  key2 : value2
}
```

Comment: where is this string stored? This is not a valid python string. Is it written in a file?

Comment: I guess it's within `''`, or in triple quotes

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am reading this string from a file. So far, tried to use findall() and search() through regex.

Comment: When you say you are reading this from a file, is this all on a single line?

Comment: Who created this file?  I suggest finding them, kicking them in the shins, and telling them to use something like JSON instead.  It's very close as-is, but just different enough to be really annoying.

Comment: @user2487274 Please [edit] and add your best attempt. We're not going to do all your work for you. Show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Yes, this content is an output from a sql query which was exported in a csv format.

Comment: @JonSG I rolled back your edit because it should be a comment instead.

Comment: @wjandrea That is of course your prerogative. I anticipated a bunch of incorrect attempts and felt that explicitly highlighting that a simple `json.loads()` is not the answer would head them off.

Comment: @user2487274 Here is one way to do so using regex: https://onecompiler.com/python/3xx42un3r.

Answer (score 1):

```
string = '"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key1":"value3,value4"'

temp = {}
for kv in string.split('","'):
    kv = kv.replace('"', '')
    k, v = kv.split(":")
    vv = v.split(",")

    if k not in temp:
        temp[k] = vv
    else:
        temp[k] += vv
```

First, let's split the string by `","` to get all the key:value pairs.
Then, let's remove all the oraphned `"`s.
Then, let's split each key:value by `:` so separate them.
Then, let's split values by `,` (turning all values into lists).
Then, we populate `temp` based on if key `k` already exists or not.

Finally if a value is a list of length 1 let's replace it with the first element.

```
outcome = {k: v[0] if len(v) == 1 else v for k, v in temp.items()}
```